# Class templated on type and "getter"

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class template that is parameterized by a type and a function for extracting a value for that type

```
template <class T, class getT>
class MyClass{
  //holds a vector of T
  std::vector<T> Ts;
  function useTs(){
     f(getT{}(Ts[0])); 
  }
};

struct TGetter{
  someType operator()(const ConcreteT& myT){
     return myT.aField;
  }
}
struct TGetter2{
  someType operator()(const ConcreteT& myT){
     return myT.bField;
  }
}
MyClass<myT, TGetter> myInstance; 
MyClass<myT, TGetter2> myInstance2;
```

Is there a more elegant way to express this idiom?  I don't like having to instantiate the struct every time I want to get at the field in a T.  I assume the construction/method call will get optimized out, but it seems like an ugly solution.  I wanted to pass a lambda as a template parameter, but I didn't think passing a function value was possible, so I used a struct type instead.

A bit of context: I have a set of physics objects and I have an acceleration structure that I need to construct using a few different state vectors of each object (currentPosition, oldPosition, etc).

Comment: I don't get why you don't call those getters directly ?

Comment: In the class template?  Look at the instantiations at the bottom.  I use the same T parameter with 2 different getters.  I'm not sure what you're suggesting.

Comment: I'm just wondering what you dont just call myT.aField when you need it instead of using templates wrapping that call.

Comment: @quantdev he sometimes wants the samefunction to call bfield.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your idiom, you are reinventing the [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) , a *general-purpose polymorphic function wrapper*, and a powerful way to encapsulate a function in C++.

```
myT foo1;
myT foo2;

std::function<void(myT)> getter1= &myT::TGetter;
getter1(foo1);
getter1(foo2);


std::function<void(myT)> getter2= &myT::TGetter2;
getter2(foo1);
getter2(foo2);

// etc...
```

The nice thing is that you will be able to encapsulate member and non member functions, lambdas and free functions.

Comment: Yeah, but then I'd have to store getter1 or getter2 in my class as opposed to passing my struct type as a template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

well, there are several options:

1) ugly solution: give a memory offset. and retrieve it from memory. This does not need to be templated.

2) more elegant solution (imo) :

save a function pointer in MyClass like this:

```
someType (T::*m_fptr)(const T&);
```

initialize the pointer in the constructor (not as templateparameter), with a getter and setter that is defined in concreteT.

3) template version of 2 is explainer here

[Passing a pointer to a member function as a template argument. Why does this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882740/passing-a-pointer-to-a-member-function-as-a-template-argument-why-does-this-wor)

I do not understand though what you mean with "function UseTs..." so it might not be the good solution, hope I could help

Comment: UseTs is just showing that even though I store T's in the class, I want to pick out a particular field (in the example below it's aField or bField) from T, and do some computation with it.  I guess I should have noted that f expects a `someType` parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using templates, I'd use [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).